# Removing Google Map Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an html checkbox that runs an if else javascript function depending on whether it is check or unchecked.  When the checkbox is checked it loads the markers called "Fishmark" from the DB.  This works fine.

What I need help with is getting the markers to remove when the box is unchecked.  I know the if, else statement is correct so it has be with the actual Google API code.  I successfully used the setMap(null) on another part of my site so I'm kinda lost as to why its not taking all of the Fishmark markers off the map.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx");     
function addRemoveFishing(){
    if(checkbox.checked==true){
        fishingUrl("XML_Fishing.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var title = markers[i].getAttribute("title");
      var water_type = markers[i].getAttribute("water_type");
      var water_depth = markers[i].getAttribute("water_depth");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var bait = markers[i].getAttribute("bait");
    var fish = markers[i].getAttribute("fish");
    var notes = markers[i].getAttribute("notes");

      var Fishhtml = "<b>" + title + "</b> <br/>" + water_type + "</b> <br/>" + water_depth + "</b> <br/>" + bait
      + "</b> <br/>" + fish + "</b> <br/>" + notes;
      var icon = FishingIcon;
     var Fishmark = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow4(Fishmark, map, Fishinfo, Fishhtml);
                        }
    });
    }
    else {
        Fishmark.setMap(null);
    }
};
```

Comment: Change "var Fishmark = new google.maps.Marker({"   
to  
"Fishmark = new google.maps.Marker({". The "var" keyword makes it a local variable so it will not be defined the second time it's run. Please note solving like this is bad javascript practice. Just pointing out what is wrong.

Comment: I took off the 'var' and it is still not removing the markers.

Comment: Sorry, missed the for loop in the code. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating several markers in a for loop. In your else statement you are only removing one (1) marker from the map.

Store the markers in an array for instance and in your else statement make a for loop that calls setMap(null) for each marker.